# Managing integers in a list

Tags: python, list

I have two lists like this:

`[2005, [4, 5, 6, 7], 2006, [4, 5, 6, 4]]`

```
[7, 6]
```

First list: Year followed by a new list with values, 2005 contains the values 4,5,6 and 7.
Second list: Contains the maximum values from the list within the first list.

**Problem:**

To output every year, followed by every value with a str saying "local max" and "all time high". E.g in my case:

```
2005  
4    
5    
6   
7 (local max)(all time high)  

2006    
4   
5   
6 (local max)   
4
```

I'm rather stuck here, I've tried some different approaches but I'm not sure how to really compare the values and then attach a string to it. I guess I need to convert my values to strings to be able to append my text?

**SOLUTION**:

Sorry again for the topic with lack of information/effort. I will know present my solution in hope of other newbies, like myself, to learn something from my experience.

```
A = [2005, [4, 5, 6, 7], 2006, [4, 5, 6, 4]]
B = [7, 6]
all_years = A[::2]

while n < all_years - 1:
    for month_list in A[1::2]:
        k = 0
        print(all_years[n])
        for every_month in month_list:
            k += 1
            attr = ''
            if every_month == max(month_list):
                attr = '(local max)'
            if every_month == max(B):
                attr += '(all time high)'
            print("""")
        n += 1
```

Comment: What have you tried ? "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist."

Comment: Hi and appologies. Next time I will thoroughly follow that guide. I will atleast answer what solved my question and how I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `zip` function, and some clever list slicing to do this in a quite clean way.

```
A = [2005, [4, 5, 6, 7], 2006, [4, 5, 6, 4]]
B = [7, 6]
global_max = max(B)

for year, year_list, max_year in zip(A[::2], A[1::2], B):
    print year
    for year_val in year_list:
        if year_val == global_max:
             print year_val, "(local max) (global max)"             
        elif year_val == max_year:
             print year_val, "(local max)"
        else:
             print year_val
```

`A[::2]` simply takes every second item in the `A` list, starting with the first item. `A[1::2]` does the same, but starts at the second item. `zip` simply creates a new list-of-lists that we can use to get correspondences between them.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. 

Since I am using python 3.x and also trying to learn to use the fundamental tools, I didn't want to use that zip-function. What solved my problem was the slicing method. Quite emberassing for me actually but I find it hard to remember all the different functions; to see where I can use the different tools for different areas.